# Simplifying formula with Laplacians

Tags: calculus

Given a streamfunction $\psi(x,y)$ and some constant scalar $\alpha$, I have the following quantity:

$$\psi \Delta((-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}\psi)$$

And am looking get this in its simplest form. Can I perhaps group the $\Delta$ to get:

$$\begin{align}
& \psi (-(-\Delta))((-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}\psi)\\
= &\psi (-(-\Delta)^{(\alpha+2)/2}\psi)
\end{align}$$

I'm stumbling here, my simplification attempts appear to be counterproductive. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any of this to make sense, you'd need to define what it means to take arbitrary powers of the Laplacian. For instance, in a suitable Fourier setting $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ corresponds to multiplication by $k^\alpha$ in Fourier space. In that case your simplification works, and in fact it should work for any definition of exponentiation that deserves that name.